# How do I add Typescript definitions for Leaflet plugins

Tags: typescript, leaflet

I would like to use easy-buttons plugin with Typescript https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.js and but it doesn't come with Typescript annotations.

Answer (score 23):

## Step 1 - light up the errors

The first step is to use the sample code as-is without Typescript annotations, and the errors will start lighting up in VS Code.

```
// sample.ts
L.easyBar([
  L.easyButton('fa-file', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-save', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-edit', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-dot-circle-o', function(btn, map){ })
]).addTo(map);
```

To which we create a file called 'easy-button.d.ts' and refer to it in our Typescript file.

```
// sample.ts
import "./easy-button"
L.easyBar([
  L.easyButton('fa-file', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-save', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-edit', function(btn, map){ }),
  L.easyButton('fa-dot-circle-o', function(btn, map){ })
]).addTo(map);
```

And there's nothing in easy-button.d.ts

```
// easy-button.d.ts
// empty for now
```

The error says

```
error TS2339: Property 'easyBar' does not exist on type 'typeof L'.
error TS2339: Property 'easyButton' does not exist on type 'typeof L'.
```

Which is fair enough because we haven't defined these yet.

If you refer to definition of `easyBar` and `easyButton` [here](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.js#L85) and [here](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.js#L312), you will find there's a bit of magic occuring in the original Javascript declarations. It appears that these two functions don't take any arguments, but in reality they do.

```
L.easyButton = function(/* args will pass automatically */){
  var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply([L.Control.EasyButton],arguments);
  return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(L.Control.EasyButton, args));
};
```

This function is going to call `new` on the `L.Control.EasyButton` class. The parameters are somewhat cryptic but you can infer them from [this line](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.js#L120) that gives:

```
initialize: function(icon, onClick, title, id)
```

## Step 2 - add the typings

```
// easy-button.d.ts
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar();
    function easyButton();
}
```

and now we are a bit closer:

```
error TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target
```

and that's quite obvious because we supplied 2 parameters 'fa-edit' and a callback to `easyButton` but we didn't declare any in our arguments. Our second attempt now looks like this:

```
// easy-button.d.ts
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar(buttons: any[]);
    function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void);
}
```

and now all the Typescript warnings have gone away. But there's more that can be done. For one, `easyButton` actually takes 4 arguments. That's easy to fix - observe how optional arguments have a `?` suffix:

```
// easy-button.d.ts
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar(buttons: any[]);
    function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void, title?: string, id?: string);
}
```

## Step 3 - provide return values

The `easyButton` method actually returns an `L.Control.EasyButton` instance. Currently, the Typescript definition implies the `easyButton` returns type `any`. We don't want that! Typescript is helpful only when we provide typings.

```
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar(buttons: Control.EasyButton[]): Control.EasyBar;
    function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void, title?: string, id?: string) : Control.EasyButton;

    namespace Control {
        class EasyButton { };
        class EasyBar { };
    }
}
```

Typescript starts providing useful warnings again:

```
error TS2339: Property 'addTo' does not exist on type 'EasyBar'.
```

This is because EasyBar subclasses `L.Control` we need to bring that definition into our definition file.

```
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar(buttons: Control.EasyButton[]): Control.EasyBar;
    function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void, title?: string, id?: string) : Control.EasyButton;

    namespace Control {
        class EasyButton extends L.Control { }
        class EasyBar extends L.Control { }
    }
}
```

## Step 4 - provide constructor arguments to EasyButton and EasyBar

If you try to instantiate a new EasyButton, code completion suggests that you should pass in a `L.ControlOptions` object to configure this. Actually we need to define our own options.[image: Code completion]

```
declare namespace L {
    function easyBar(buttons: Control.EasyButton[], options?: EasyBarOptions): Control.EasyBar;
    function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void, title?: string, id?: string) : Control.EasyButton;

    interface EasyBarOptions {
        position?: ControlPosition
        id?: string
        leafletClasses?: boolean
    }

    interface EasyButtonOptions {
        position?: ControlPosition
        id?: string
        type?: 'replace'|'animate'
        states?: any
        leafletClasses?: boolean
        tagName?: string
    }

    namespace Control {
        class EasyButton extends L.Control {
            constructor(options?: EasyButtonOptions)
        }
        class EasyBar extends L.Control {
            constructor(options?: EasyBarOptions)
        }
    }
}
```

Things look better now on code completion: [image: new EasyButton code completion]

However, I cheated on the `states` option. I declared that as `any`. In actuality it ought to be

```
    interface EasyButtonOptions {
        position?: ControlPosition
        id?: string
        type?: 'replace'|'animate'
        states?: EasyButtonState[]
        leafletClasses?: boolean
        tagName?: string
    }

    interface EasyButtonState {
        stateName: string
        onClick: () => void
        title: string
        icon: string
    }
```

## Step 5 - add jsdoc hints

Typescript will provide helpful comments to users of this plugin. Here's an example of how we might provide documentation for `easyButton`

```
   /**
     * Creates a easyButton
     * @param icon e.g. fa-globe
     * @param onClick the button click handler
     * @param label on the button
     * @param an id to tag the button with
     * @example
     * var helloPopup = L.popup().setContent('Hello World!');
     *
     * L.easyButton('fa-globe', function(btn, map){
     *      helloPopup.setLatLng(map.getCenter()).openOn(map);
     *  }).addTo( YOUR_LEAFLET_MAP );
     */
    function easyButton(
        icon: string,
        onClick: (btn: Control.EasyButton, map: L.Map) => void,
        title?: string,
        id?: string): Control.EasyButton;
```

## Step 6 Make modifications to augment leaflet types definitions

(Starting with Leaflet 1.2.0) Remove the namespace declaration:

```
declare namespace L {
```

and replace it with module augmentation:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
declare module 'leaflet' {
```

your test code should now read like this:

```
import * as L from 'leaflet'
import 'easy-button'
```

## Step 7 integrate into the original project sources

Open up `node_modules\leaflet-easybutton\package.json` and add the following line below the `style` entry:

```
  "main": "src/easy-button.js",
  "style": "src/easy-button.css",
  "typings": "src/easy-button.d.ts",
```

Move our `easy-button.d.ts` into `node_modules/leaflet-easybutton/src`, and test that everything still works.

Then submit a pull request so that every one can benefit from the work!

Comment: Your easy button constructor interface doesn't include the initialize methods of the L.easyButton

Comment: Thanks Steve, I had a look and wasnt sure what you meant there. The typings are here https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton/blob/master/src/easy-button.d.ts and if you file an issue on Github we can discuss it there.

Comment: Exactly what I need! Been looking for it for hours, thank you, Chui!

Comment: Thanks for this very informative answer! I'm still trying to wrap my head around how TypeScript works (for example, how can `L.Control` be both a class and a namespace?), but these are exactly the sort of examples I needed to help me write types for a different leaflet plugin.

Answer (score 4):

It actually does now. You should just

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button';
```

Comment: This worked for me. However I had to add @import 'leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button/easy-button.css'; to the top of styles.scss instead of adding the css reference directly in the component. I'm using Angular 12.

Answer (score 0):

`class EasyButton extends L.Control {
            constructor(options?: EasyButtonOptions)
        }`

Your new L.EasyButton takes a 'EasyButtonOptions' object for the constructor.  This does not match the 'L.easyButton' examples

A L.easyButton has the following options:

`function easyButton(icon: string, onClick: (btn: any, map: any)=>void, title?: string, id?: string) : Control.EasyButton;`

An EasyButtonOptions doesn't have a 'icon', 'onClick', 'title' or 'id' instead it takes:

`interface EasyButtonOptions {
        position?: ControlPosition
        id?: string
        type?: 'replace'|'animate'
        states?: EasyButtonState[]
        leafletClasses?: boolean
        tagName?: string
    }`

So therefore, what is the equivalent of new L.EasyButton() that matches L.easyButton('fa fa-icon', () => '..', 'title) ?

Comment: Hi Steve, there are two functions exported by the module, a `easyButton` function, and a `EasyButton` class. The class constructor has to be called `new L.EasyButton(...)` while the easyButton function will give you a new EasyButton instance. Hope I've explained it well enough. :)