# Angular or webpack is loading the leaflet library twice

Tags: angular, webpack, leaflet, angular-cli

Having loading leaflet and one of its plugins:

```
npm i leaflet
npm i @types/leaflet
npm i leaflet-minimap
```

and included them in the scripts of `.angular-cli.json`

```
  "scripts": [
    "../src/assets/js/break-on.js",
    "../node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
    "../node_modules/leaflet-minimap/src/Control.MiniMap.js",
```

Referencing the leaflet library reloads the whole src file, and this overwrites the plugins on the global `L` object

so, at initialisation:

`L.control` is set up by leaflet and then the Minimap plugin ensures `L.control.minimap`

then in code

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
```

after that

```
L.control.minimap
```

is undefined

I am unsure whether this is an angular, angular-cli, webpack or leaflet issue

I have checked and the `leaflet.js` source file is initialised twice, and it is this line that does it the second time < why is that not only the types??

```
import * as L from "leaflet";
```

ng -v =>

```
Angular CLI: 1.7.3
Node: 8.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.2.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.7.3
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/core: 0.3.2
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.3.2
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.2.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.10.2
@schematics/angular: 0.3.2
@schematics/package-update: 0.3.2
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.11.0
leaflet: 1.3.1
```

The first source is scripts.bundle
The second source is vendor.bundle

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472856/how-do-i-add-typescript-definitions-for-leaflet-plugins

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe thanks but in what respect exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plugins that modify a global L variable
In this case, you have to import the whole Leaflet module into L. Then, you import the plugin library for side-effects. This is illustrated in the following snippet taken from the leaflet-path-transform example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// Import Leaflet into L 
import * as L from 'leaflet';

// Import the plugin libraries so they will modify L
import 'leaflet-path-transform';
import 'leaflet-path-drag';

@Component({
...
```

taken from: https://www.asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-and-leaflet-plugins/