# Extending leaflet in typescript

Tags: typescript, leaflet, typescript-typings

I'm using `webpack@2.6` with `typescript@2.0`.
I installed `leaflet` and also `leaflet-routing-machine`
I import them like this.

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import {Map} from 'leaflet';
import "leaflet-routing-machine";
```

But typescript does not knows `Routing` in `L.Routing.control({})`

How to define it? Code below is not working.

```
interface L {
  Routing: any;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a 5-year-old question, but with more recent versions of Typescript, you may find this SO answer useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44472857

The gist of it is, use [Typescript Module Augumentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) to "extend" leaflet type definitions. In your case, this would look something like:

```
declare module "leaflet" {
    namespace Routing {
        // type definitions for stuff inside Routing, i.e.:
        function control(): () => any
    }
}
```